# Determining the greater of two circles using distance between random points inside them

Tags: geometry, circles, statistical-inference

Suppose we have 2 circles of unequal radii, A and B, and we do not know which is greater.
We have n random points inside each circle, and we have the distance between every pair of points inside the circles.

For example, for 10 random points inside A and 10 random points inside B, we have the distances between the 45 pairs of points in A and 45 pairs of points in B.

How do we determine which circle has the greater radius?

Comment: Clarification requested: "How do we determine which circle has the greater radius?" As stated, this is impossible, so I am guessing that you are **really asking** what is the probability that circle A has a greater radius than circle B.  See next comment.

Comment: Suppose that circle A has a radius of $3$ and circle B has a radius of $2$.  Consider the concentric circle of radius $1$ inside of circle A.  If all $10$ points chosen from circle A are inside this (much smaller) concentric circle, you would clearly have no way of **proving** that circle A is larger than circle B.

Answer (score 0):

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem) shows you how to find the smallest circle enclosing a set of points. The algorithms are not trivial, but the second one (Wlezl's algorithm) looks doable. And I think this is all you need to determine which set of points is more likely to belong to the smaller circle.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but *how much* more likely?  The (much) more complicated question is unambiguous and therefore should be exactly computable.  However, I question whether the approach in your answer would facilitate an exact answer.

Comment: @user2661923: I don't know about exactly computable. Given a circle $A$ with a known radius, and $n$ random points inside it, the distribution of the radius of the smallest enclosing circle is unambiguous, although (as you say) not amenable to easy computation. But here we have the the reverse problem $-$ given a set of points, what is the distribution of the radius of circle $A$? This is not well-posed; it depends on the _a priori_ distribution of possible radii of $A$. This is the domain of [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).

Comment: Rebuttal by thought experiment.  Of the known $\binom{10}{2}$ distances, let $2M$ denote the max and $m$ denote the min so the unknown circle must have a radius of at least $M$.  Set a point-distance tolerance of $\frac{m}{1000}$ and a radius gap of $\frac{M}{1000}$.  For each radius in $$M \times k : k \in \{1, 1 + (1/1000), 1 + (2/1000) + \cdots + 2 + \cdots + 1000\}$$ perform the following experiment (perhaps via computer)... See next comment

Comment: For each specific circle, perform 10000 trials.  In each trial, randomly pick $10$ points from inside the circle.  Sort the $45$ distances in ascending order, and then count the trial as a success if and only if the $45$ distances match up with the known $45$ distances, based on the point-distance tolerance of $\frac{m}{1000}$.  Attach a weight to the specific radius that corresponds to the number of successful trials, out of 10000.  ...see next comment

Comment: Since you are perfoming this experiment for each radius between $1 \times M$ and $1000 \times M$ inclusive, with a radius gap of $\frac{M}{1000}$, you will have $1000001$ weights, based on the previous comment.  You can then use these weights to determine the expected value of the unknown radius of the circle.

Comment: @user2661923: Yes. This is maximum likelihood estimation, based on the assumption that the _a priori_ distribution of the radius of $A$ is uniform in $[M,2M]$ (if I have understood your $M\times k$ typo correctly). It's a good practical approach, but it doesn't give an exact answer (because an exact answer is impossible without making such an assumption about the distribution).

Comment: The points are distributed uniformly. The answer should be a statistical test that rejects or confirms the null hypothesis: radius of A > radius of B.

Comment: @HenbaneDatura: Do you just want to know which is more likely? Or do you want to know the _probability_ that $r_A>r_B$? If so, then the discussion in the comments is relevant.